# Better way to remove items from combobox - c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using c# 4.0 have following line of code:

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(all);
comboBox.Items.Remove("abc");
```

Is there a better way to write this? Like can this be written in one line? So that even before adding abc comboBox can check for this and dont add it at first place?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to filter what you ask it to add so you can do something like this : `comboBox.Items.NeverEverTake("abc");` and then `comboBox.Items.Add("abc"); //does nothing`? Or are you trying to filter only `all` to have something like `comboBox.Items.AddRange(all.Except("abc"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(all.Where(x => x != "abc").ToArray());
```